# Image Slideshow Script

Tags: javascript, image, slideshow

I want to display images as a slideshow. I have a link and title for every image.

When looping through the images I also want the image link and title to change accordingly.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please feed google with the tags of your question, choose one of the many solutions and then tell us, if you have specific problems working with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Javascript is better than php for this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PHP to make slideshow. You use javascript to make slideshow.

Check out this link:

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Let me give you a simple jquery fading slideshow

HTML

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="img/img1.jpg" alt="" class="active" />
    <img src="img/img2.jpg" alt="" />
    <img src="img/img3.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

Some JQuery

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next()
        : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

Oh! yes, don't forget to import jquery library